# How to pick out dates. In Excel

Tags: excel

I want to pick out “Month/day” from string like “2023/7/13  0:31:19”.
I tried to it by using a function,LEFT() and RIGHT(),
but it didn’t work.
For example

| Number | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/7/13 0:31:19 | RIGHT (A1,5) |

I guessed B1 would be “31:19”,but it was practically
“76852”.
Please tell me how to pick out.

Comment: That looks like a valid date/time format to me - as such, `=INT(A1)` and `=MOD(A1,1)` should work.

Comment: Do you merely need to display "month/day", or do you really need the cell value to contain only "month/day" as text?

Comment: I need the latter.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks you for reply, and I tried it. But It didn’t work right. Such as, There were 2023/7/13 0:31:19(Cell A1), and I wrote INT(A1). But INT(A1) show me a value,” 2023/7/13 0:00
“.

Comment: Because you haven't amended the cell format appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=MONTH(A1)&"/"&DAY(A1)
```

Comment: Really Thank you for your answer. It works successfully. And let me ask another question. How to pick out time?

Comment: Eventually I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value in cell A1 is a valid date/time (not a text string), there are a few options you can use, depending on the results you're expecting:

| Formula | Results |
| --- | --- |
| `=MONTH(A1)` | 7 |
| `=DAY(A1)` | 13 |
| `=YEAR(A1)` | 2023 |
| `=HOUR(A1)` | 0 |
| `=MINUTE(A1)` | 31 |
| `=SECOND(A1)` | 19 |
| `=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd")` | "07/13" |
| `=TEXT(A1,"mmm")` | "Jul" |
| `=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")` | "July" |
| `=TEXT(A1,"ddd")` | "Thu" |
| `=TEXT(A1,"dddd")` | "Thursday" |
| `=TEXT(A1,"h:mm AM/PM")` | "12:31 AM" |

Mix and match the above methods to return the desired results.